# Is there any trouble using nwjs with an ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, nwjs

I developed an ionic application, and I want to use NWjs to make it as a desktop APP.
Is there any trouble to use NWjs with an ionic app or should I develop a new app?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly move your project to the directory of NW binary file
and adding `"main": "www/index.html"` of `package.json`
and that all
this is a link point to another same question [Integration of Ionic framework and nw.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262149/integration-of-ionic-framework-and-nw-js)