# JavaScript navigator user agent returns "iPhone" for iPad Pro with iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a hybrid app which is built with Ionic framework, and to determine whether the user is on iPad or iPhone, I am using the userAgent data from navigator object.

Following is the code:

`navigator.userAgent`

this works well with the older version of iPads.

But for the latest iPad Pro (which has a iOS 10) it returns device as "iPhone" raturns than "iPad".

Comment: why don't you use cordova-plugin-device instead?

Comment: @jcesarmobile It's useful to detect iPad and iPhone but for android I didn't find any method which can tell me that the user is on android mobile or on android tablet. Actually I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18862499/4501514) code

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for accurately detecting devices:

1. You can use the `ionic.Platform` utility methods documented here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/
2. You can use `cordova-plugin-device` documented here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/

I find it is easier to use `ionic.Platform` because it is already included in Ionic. It also has the method `ionic.Platform.isIPad()` which will return `true` if the user is on an iPad. And that sounds like what you need!

Comment: It's useful to detect iPad and iPhone but for android I didn't find any method which can tell me that the user is on android mobile or on android tablet.

Comment: It looks like you could use `device.model` from `cordova-plugin-device` to detect android mobile/tablet, but it will take a bit more custom configuration. You could also detect the screen size to roughly determine mobile/tablet.